# How to solve this problem with the API Graph of facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fetch-api

I using the API graph to get data from my post and part of that is change the "order"
of the comments from "ranked" to "chronological" to get all the comments and the response, the problem came when I try get the data of the comments with/with out the filter from a specific kind of post.

The only similarity I can see is when other person posted directly from the plataform and not from HubSpot

This is the call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/{post_id}/comments?summary=1&total_count(true)&filter=stream
```

This is the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#200) Missing Permissions",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 200,
        "fbtrace_id": "ARgqjIXa_foc862xq-7sdod"
    }
}
```

I have a roll of analyst, my app is already active and the permissions of my app are this:

- read_insights
- pages_show_list
- ads_management
- ads_read
- instagram_basic
- instagram_manage_insights
- pages_read_engagement
- pages_read_user_content
- public_profile

Anyone know why this happening?